# Basic authentication in android using Volley for GIthub. Getting error code 422

Tags: android, rest, authentication, github-api

The below code returns authentication failure with error 422. I want to use basic authentication to login into my Github account. Please tell me where I am doing wrong

```
    JsonObjectRequest request =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://api.github.com/user", object, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.d("success","Successfully logged in");
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e("Error", "Error with authentication");
    }
}){
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String loginEncoded = new String(Base64.encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + loginEncoded);
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return headers;
    }
};
requestQueue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the problem was. I did not think of the possibility that it can be a GET request. I changed the REQUEST.Method.POST to REQUEST.Method.GET and it worked. 
Yes, I know. I am still a noob when it comes to stuff related to the web.

Comment: Nice catch, more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your json content: [Error 422 means "Unprocessable Entity"](http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity):

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means:
>
> - the server understands the content type of the request entity,
> - and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate)
> - but was unable to process the contained instructions.
>
> For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.